# validate and return red

Tags: javascript, html

am trying to check all inputbox which are null to show red rounded on that null box

but i dont know why its not working out for me, i have a problem in my javascript

i need help in my javascript to validate all inputbox before submitting

```js
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var y, i, valid = true;
  y = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field 
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

```css
/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <div>Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sndm">

</form>
```

Comment: `"ReferenceError: sndm is not defined",` when you click the submit button. Please either add that function in your snippet's Javascript section *if it's relevant to your question*, or remove `onclick="sndm"`.

Comment: also you might want to do individual fields or the specific form vs all `input`'s as some inputs need diff validations, like email, passwords, address, age etc

Comment: Also note that HTML and Javascript have a solution for the wheel you're trying to reinvent. Check the `required` attribute in HTML, and the `element.validity` object in JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use string comparison to find empty fields. HTML has the `required`-attribute for this, and it reflects in the `element.validity` object.

```js
const textInputs = document
  .getElementById('regForm')
  .querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

function validateForm() {
  return textInputs.every(input => input.validity.valid)
}
```

```css
/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <div>Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." name="fname" required type="text"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." name="lname" required type="text"></p>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

To prevent form submission with empty fields, you don't even need Javascript:

```css
/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <div>Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." name="fname" required type="text"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." name="lname" required type="text"></p>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: am using onclick to submit, onclick doesn't check work with required like submit because my button type is button not submit so it wont work with required

Answer (score 0):

You can use default property "required" of HTML which validate the form and also provides default tooltip to make it more used friendly, which prevent to submit invalid form as well.

See below example :

CSS

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

HTML

```
  <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <h1>Register:</h1>
      <div>Name:
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="First name..." required name="fname"></p>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Last name..." required name="lname"></p>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    
    </form>
```